# No errors when runs on netbeans but not when running the jar?

Tags: java, jar, sms, smslib

When I run my program which use smslib works fine when I run it on netbeans, But when I generated the jar file and run it, the console shows me this error. Any thoughts on how to solve it? Your help will be much appreciated.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (smslib).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java:69)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: CommPortIdentifier class not found
    at org.smslib.helper.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:76)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Probably classpath issue check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: Did you check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253712/smslib-doesnt-send-sms-with-e226-3g-modem ?

Answer (score 0):

The `smslib` library is not on runtime classpath or the runtime classpath is not setup correctly.